# CSS: 2 sided 3D flip overlapping / bleeding

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to implement a 3D flip effect using two faces in IE (no `preserve-3d`). See this CodePen for an example: http://codepen.io/djskinner/pen/XbdPpj

The problem is that the two faces overlap at the edges. The issue is present in both Chrome and IE so I assume that there is a problem in the way I have converted this effect to take account for the lack of `preserve-3d` in IE. Is there a way to prevent this from occurring?

[image: example]

Comment: Can describe _"the two faces overlap at the edges. "_ ?

Comment: I have added an image to the description which offers a better explanation

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved the effect without any glitches by utilising the `transform-origin` property, which then allowed a simple rotation rather than having to perform rotations and translations.

Updated code pen can be found here: http://codepen.io/djskinner/pen/NqNVPx.

Inspiration taken from this code pen: http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/xiJLn.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an update of your codepen your origin's where updated and I have also added a z-index to your active state so that on hover you cant see the hidden div at the bottom of your 3d box.

hope it helps.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJymRP

```js
$('.cube').hover(function(event) {
  $(this).addClass('active');
  event.preventDefault();
}, function(event) {
  $(this).removeClass('active');
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
$cube-height: 100px;
$negative-half-cube-height: -0.5*$cube-height;

.cube {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: $cube-height;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

// The two faces of the cube
.default-state,
.active-state {
  backface-visibility: visible;
  height: $cube-height;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: transform 1.5s ease;
  transform-origin: center center  $negative-half-cube-height;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center center  $negative-half-cube-height;
  width: 100%;
}

// Position the faces
.default-state {
  background-color: #1d92c9;
  transform:perspective(1000px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
}

.active-state {
 transform:perspective(1000px) rotateX(90deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg);
}
.active {

  .default-state {

    transform:perspective(1000px) rotateX(-90deg) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0deg);
  }

  .active-state {
    z-index:99999;
  transform:perspective(1000px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0);
  }
}

/* Demo styling */
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 70px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.cube {
   text-align: center;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.default-state, .active-state {
  background: #2ecc71;
  
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: $cube-height;
}

.active-state {
  background: darken(#2ecc71, 7%);
}

#flipto {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<h1>3D FLIP IN IE</h1>

<div class="cube">
   <div class="active-state">
      <span>...and I flip</span>
   </div>
  <div class="default-state">
      <span>Hover</span>
   </div>

</div>
```